# Android: How to make only one word became bold in TextView

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragments

I'm trying to make only one word with bold style and set this in a TextView: 
My text cames from an endpoint as:

"bla bla bla `<b>Hello</b>` bla"

What I've tried, but nothing happens, the Android ignores the  tags:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(PlanoHolder holder, int position) {
    Spanned x = HtmlCompat.fromHtml(item.getDesc(), HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY);
    textView.setText(x.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's happen because `x` is converting `toString` again. Just pass the `Spanned` as below

```
Spanned x = HtmlCompat.fromHtml(item.getDesc(), HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY);
textView.setText(x);
```